# How do I run queries in R using IF statements instead of subsets?

Tags: r, if-statement

I'd imagine this is a fairly easy question -- but I can't quite figure out how to write code on partial parts of my dataset without creating a new subset every time.

For example, if I have a dataset called `dataset` and a column called `gender` and another called `age` and I only want to run a query on the females over 30, I could easily create a subset of the dataset which would work fine by writing:

```
female30plus <- subset(dataset,dataset$gender == "female" & dataset$age > 30)
```

Then I could easily run numbers or make graphs simply using `female30plus` -- but if I didn't want to create a million subsets of `dataset`, I'd imagine there's a fairly easy way to run these numbers just using some form of an `IF` statement -- even though most of what I'm trying doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks for the help!

--

**Answer:**

The answer is in the comments of the answer below, but in case anybody had the same question, you should use `dataset[dataset$gender == "female" & dataset$age > 30,]` if you don't want to create a subset each time. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You need to specify what sort of combination of criteria you are thinking of using. M/F and what sort of age criteria? AND don't use `dataset$` in front of column names inside subset. It completely defeats the purpose of the function.

Comment: @BondedDust    Sorry -- confused about what I'm missing. Didn't think I needed to post a dataset, since it was just a question about how to stop using subsets all the time. My dataset currently has a length of only 199, with 61 females, and ages ranging from 31 to 88 (with a mean of 60). What else would be helpful?

Comment: It wasn't clear what you wanted. I don't see an advantage to using `dataset[dataset[,2] >= 30 & dataset[,1] == "female",]` over using `subset(dataset, gender == "female" & age > 30)`. They are both doing sub-setting operations and the `subset` version is clearer and has less typing.

Comment: @BondedDust    I just wanted code that wouldn't force me to create a million subsets. I agree with you that I wish `dataset[dataset[,2] >= 30 & dataset[,1] == "female",]` wasn't so clunky and I was hoping there'd be a simpler way to do it without being overruled with subsets, but if now I know there's not a simple `if-then`-type statement to write it, I might just continue using subsets.

Comment: @BondedDust    For example, I use SQL more than R -- and to me, creating subsets for everything in R seemed similar like creating new tables in SQL every time I wanted to look at different parts of the dataset, which I would never do.

Comment: There is some conceptual error in your understanding of what R is doing. Executing the `subset` function does exactly the same thing as executing the `[` function with a logical argument. If you choose not to assign the value to a name then the result is not going to reside in the workspace.

Comment: @BondedDust    Yup, and that's what I wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but you should beable to work with something like this.

```
dataset[dataset[,2] >= 30 & dataset[,1] == "female",]
```

If you specify `TRUE` or `false` in a dataset like `dataset[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` it will only return data that lands on `TRUE`. So here you're just inputting an argument then will return `TRUE` only if the data fits both your conditions.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Two questions just to help understand: (1) Is there any way to do it without counting the columns? For example, age in mine is column 17 and gender is column 2 -- is there a way to do that without looking that up every time? And (2) In your example, what would happen if you added something to the x in `dataset[x,2]`?

Comment: `dataset[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` will return every other column. I would advise waiting until the questioner has posted enough detail to figure out what he really wants. Then test.

Comment: @Ryan in reply to your first question, absolutely: if the names are the constant rather than the column position, you can use names. So, dataset[dataset$age >= 30 & dataset$gender == "female",]

Comment: @Ironholds     Thanks! `dataset[dataset$age >= 30 & dataset$gender == "female",]` was pretty much exactly what I was looking for, since now I can create graphs, etc. on this data while not having a million subsets saved. Just so I know though, what is the last comma for -- and why doesn't it work without it?

Comment: @Ryan : the commas in the brackets separate the rows and columns - so the it is taking only rows for females older than thirty and all of the columns. You could restrict which columns are considered by adding something (e.g. column names or numbers) after the comma.

Comment: What John Paul said. So, if you look at a dataframe, you'll see it's got rows and columns; when subsetting, it's df[row-related subset commands,column-related subset commands]. If you've got a vector, it's just vector[subset commands], because it's only a single column - a 3-dimensional array, on the other hand, would be array[row,column,depth]. And there's lists, with list[[list_element]] and list[list_element's_element]. It's wonderfully confusing ;p.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I generally index columns by number rather than name because its a lot quicker to write `df[,2]` than `df$flowcfs` and I make a lot of one time use data alterations. But for your case I completely understand why you prefer naming columns. @BondedDust Ryan said my solution worked. Several other people you included have looked at this post and I don't see any superior answer or comments showing how my answer is wrong. What makes you think I didn't understand what the questioner wanted? Please reserve down votes for answers that actually don't address the question.